# Post message to chat API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We create an internal service to start different processes for different events.
Actualy this service allow to buld workflow using diferent buildins blocks-functions, sach request-block, parse-block, blocks for python code(but without ability to connect external libraryes).
These workflowes can be executed due to some trigger or schedule, gather information and send report to messagers.
As we are using Microsoft Teams, we want to implement sending messages using the API.
Here we are faced with the problem of how we can implement sending a message to the Microsoft Teams chat using the API request.
We got token by this way (Get access without a user - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)
But request(by this instraction - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Unauthorized",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-03-03T08:43:42",
            "request-id": "b30064e5-1d9f-46b7-8af3-259e44acbdd0",
            "client-request-id": "b30064e5-1d9f-46b7-8af3-259e44acbdd0"
        }
    }
}
```

As we understant right way - to get token by this way(Get access on behalf of a user - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)
But our workflow doesn't assume entering additional credentials during executing.
Workflows tools allow just send prerequest with entered before credentials.
Please tell us enter code herecan we implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can go through this [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/csharp-teams-sample-graph). You need to implement Authentication and Authorization, get the token from the AAD and then call MS Graph Team Chat API with that token.

Comment: Hi there! To help people answer your question, please describe the actions you've already taken and the research you've already done. Microsoft has plenty of API documentation, so it's not clear what problem you're facing.